# Problema con Pagina web en red local

Tags: web, apache, servidor, xampp, dns

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Tengo una pagina web ya en un servidor

Servidor 192.168.25.10(ejemplo) aqui tengo mi pagina ya con apache.

Tuve que mover el puerto ya que algunos puertos se estan utilizando entonces tengo mi pagina que es:
ejemplo-web.intranet en el puerto 82.

Ahora utilice virtual host para poner el nombre y todo, El problema es el siguiente en el servidor puedo ver mi pagina tanto escribiendo: 192.168.25.10:82 y  ejemplo-web.intranet:82 pero en otra computadora no me deja:

Si yo pongo ejemplo-web.intranet:82 **No me deja**

y si pongo 192.168.25.10:82 **Puedo ver la pagina**

y lo que necesito es escribir el nombre.

Asi tengo mis archivos:

En hosts:

```
192.168.25.10      ejemplo-web.intranet
    ::82           ejemplo-web.intranet
```

En vhosts

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.25.10:82>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\Intranet"
    ServerName ejemplo-web.intranet
    ServerAlias  www.ejemplo-web.intranet.com
</VirtualHost>
```

y en httpd

```
listen 82

ServerName ejemplo-web.intranet:82
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar con esto, gracias

Comment: La otra computadora debería tener las mismas entradas en el archivo hosts.

Comment: Okey funciono gracias, pero esto a que sebe o por que se tiene que hacer eso, ¿no hay manera de hacerlo de otra forma? digo esto es una intranet.

Comment: El concepto es *Resolución de Nombres*, que es traducir el nombre de un equipo en una dirección IP. Las alternativas que me vienen a la mente son NetBIOS (NBNS/WINS), DDNS y DNS.